# Vector of vectors to 1D array

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdvector

I was wondering if there is a clever way of presenting the information in a vector as a 1D array. Example:
Let's create a vector of vectors of 5x3 int elements

```
vector< vector<int>> iVector;
ivector.resize( 5 );
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    iVector[i].resize(3);
}
```

But now I want this structure to be converted into a 1D array:

```
int* myArray = new int[5*3];
```

So I could access each element which I want as follows:

```
for (i =0;i < 5; i++)
  for(j =0; j< 3; j++)
      myArray[i*3+j] = ...
```

I know I could just copy the vector to the array element by element, but I was wondering if there is a method that directly addresses the vector to array conversion. I also know that the vector can me addressed as `iVector[i][j]` , but unfortunately it needs to be an array as it will be sent to a GPU and GPUs dont understand vectors.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but have you tried to use a single vector instead of vector of vectors? You could arrange access that would emulate 2D array. In such way, copying vector to array is trivial

Comment: What is wrong with 2D accessing: `iVector[i][j]` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz: There is nothing wrong, but it is not possible for a GPU device

Comment: @Manolete - I see - I overlooked this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `std::copy` 5 times.

```
int* ptrArray = myArray;
for (i =0;i < 5; i++) {
  std::copy(iVector[i].begin(), iVector[i].end(), ptrArray);
  ptrArray += iVector[i].size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing you can do here except copy it into an array. The GPU will not understand any abstraction you create any more than it can understand `std::vector`. All you can do is make an array and copy it over.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors supposed to store the elements in a linear fashion, so in theory you can refer to the entire underlying vector (only a single vector):

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int data[4] = &(numbers[0]);
```

Similarily, perhaps you can try the same approach for the 2D version.
However in your place I would consider to use a class that is specifically designed to handle matrices (it is easy to write one similar to std::vector().

Comment: This approach will not work for a vector of vectors, as the [vectors are not stored contiguously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898084)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use plain old C.

You first initialize the array size to be the number of rows * the number of columns your vector of vectors has. Then you use memcpy to copy each vector to the array.

```
vector<vector<int> > v = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} }; //v is 3 by 2 matrix 
int *arr = (int*)malloc( (3*2) * sizeof(int)); // arr has size 3*2 = 6
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    memcpy(arr + v[i].size() * i, &(v[i][0]), v[i].size() * sizeof(int));
```

Here's a function that I wrote that does this for you:

```
template<typename T>
T *vectorToArray(vector<vector<T> > const &v) {
    T *rv = (T*)malloc((v.size()*v[0].size()) * sizeof(T)); //Assuming all rows have the same size
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        memcpy(rv + v[i].size() * i, &(v[i][0]), v[i].size() * sizeof(T));
    return rv;
}
```

So now you can do something like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > v = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} }; //v is 3 by 2 matrix 
int *arr = vectorToArray(v);
```

I hope this helps