# C++ data contiguity of std::vector<std::array<char, 2>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

How is the data of `std::vector<std::array<char, 2>>` laid out in memory? Could I recast the vector to `std::vector<char>` and access the contents of the arrays that way? I assume this is not the way it works, but since it is C++, I wanted to make sure. If it works the same way as `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`, I do not need an explanation since [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898007/stdvector-of-stdvectors-contiguity) explains it pretty well.

Comment: `vector<array>` differs from `vector<vector>`. `vector<array>` is contiguous, `vector<vector>` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` has less trivial layout than `std::array` does. You're trying to cast vector to a vector of a different type, even of a different size. No luck.

Answer (score -1):

> Could I recast the `vector` to `std::vector<char>` and access the contents of the arrays that way?

No, you can't. `std::vector` has richer semantics than plain old arrays and pointers. If you call any member function, it will lead to undefined behavior.

However, you can access the array as though it were an array of `char` with size `size of the vector * 2` iff your implementation of `std::array` does not use any padding. i.e. `sizeof(array<char, 2> == sizeof(char[2])`.

In that case you can use:

```
char* cp  = &(thevector[0][0]);
```

to access the contents of the array.

Comment: I think std::array is not forbidden from having some padding at the end. At least that used to be the case in C++11.

Comment: "`std::array<char, 2>` is guaranteed to hold only a `char[2]`" Nope.

Comment: If you have some evidence that this is now allowed, please answer the question this is a dupe of.

Comment: I found this "This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array T[N] as its only non-static data member." here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: @juanchopanza, point taken.

Comment: @T.C., agree. There is no mandate to prohibit use of padding.

Comment: @eclipse, unfortunately, that still does not stop an implementation from using padding.