# Is EASTL vector<vector<int>> contiguous

Tags: c++, vector, eastl

As per this answer:

[std::vector of std::vectors contiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898007/stdvector-of-stdvectors-contiguity)

A vector of vectors is not contiguous. EASTL claims that their vector is contgiuous (see: https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/vector.h it). Does this contiguity apply to a vector of vectors?

Comment: The comment you are referring to is really old, and many of the differences listed there do not apply anymore (and some of them never did). In fact [std::vector also guarantees that the elements are stored contiguously](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: BTW, if this is a requirement for something you're doing, and if the size of the inner container can be fixed, consider a [vector of arrays](https://godbolt.org/z/EGXqMA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they mean is that the memory allocated by their vectors will be contiguous.  Any memory allocated by the contained elements are not a part of this.

So yes, their vectors are contiguous.  And no, that does not apply to all the contained elements as a group.

Comment: So it's no more contigous than a regular std::vector of vectors?

Comment: That's right.  How could it be ?  There is no way to control how contained objects allocate memory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Does that mean it is better to use a multidimensional array instead of a vector of vectors to ensure contiguity? I can ask seperately.

Comment: A multidimensional array would be contiguous, but there is still no way to control how the contained objects allocate memory, if they do.