# Array.at(index) over Array[index]

Tags: c++, c++11

I start to learn `std::array` and found function to access array with `.at(index of element)`. Is there any reason to it over `array.[index of element]` style?(e.g speed, exception or other).

Comment: Did you compare the documentation for those? What did you find out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vector::at vs. vector::operator\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376049/vectorat-vs-vectoroperator)

Comment: I found answer. With .at() it checks boundary of array. Where with [] operator it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at))

```
const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
```

and ([link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at)

```
const_reference at(size_type pos) const;
```

They both return a reference to the element at the specified location: `pos`. However, the former does not perform bounds checking, whereas the latter does.
In case `!(pos < size())` the latter will throw an [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception.