# Can anyone explain the time complexity of the given code in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that the time complexity of adding a single element in a set is O[logn] . So , if I insert N elements one by one in a set that was initially empty , what should be the time complexity of this operation  ? . Please explain in detail .

PS : I think the time complexity will be O[NlogN]. Am I correct ?

Given below is the code snippet :

```
vector<int> v(n);
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
   v[i] = i;
}
set<int> s;
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
   s.insert(v[i]);
}
```

Comment: What do you *think* the answer is, and why?

Comment: are you literally asking what is N times Log(N) ?

Comment: @Cubbi: No, they are not. N is not a constant in this.

Comment: @Cubbi But 'N' is not constant .

Comment: @ChrisB: The question is what more like what is sum(O(log i) for i = 1 to n), although that is an abuse of O notation. For some functions f, sum(O(f(i)) will be O(n f(i)). For others it will not. So asking what it is for log is a reasonable question.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Whether this is a well-posed and well-researched question or not there is no need for more detail.

Comment: Here is a proof that `log(1)+log(2)+log(3) + ... = O(nlogn)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095472/3357352)

Comment: For the code provided, in this particular case, it's `O(n)`.

Comment: If you want to know about the complexity of insert look at the documentation for [std::set::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) the information is there.

Comment: @Eljay How ? It should be NlogN .

Comment: Because `v[i]` is always `0`, which eliminates the binary tree traversal cost because the tree only has the one node in it, and `insert` will always return `false` for .second (no insertion happened) after the first insertion.

Comment: @Eljay For the updated code it will be NlogN . Right ?

Comment: Yes.  With the assumption that the `set` doesn't have pathological behavior from a naïve implementation — such as generating into (effectively) a singly-linked list (a very lopsided tree) if the data happens to be pre-sorted (which in this case it is).  The `std::set` ought to be very smart, but if the `set` was a naïve implementation, it could have `O(²)` behavior.

Comment: Totally unrelated: Regarding `for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { v[i] = i; }` take a look at [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: You can speculate about this or you can just run it for varying values of N where N is a power of ten. 10, 100, 1000, etc. and surely by 10e9 you'll know what kind of curve you have if you collect data carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Time Complexity**

Edit: Assuming "ideal" conditions, no UB, no pre-sorted elements,...

Yes, you are partially correct. Adding a single element into an `std::set` is indeed `O(log(N)).

**Why?**

`std::set` is implemented as a balanced binary search tree (BBST), therefore if the element is smaller than the value you would go into the left subtree and vice-versa, hence inserting an element takes `O(log(N))` because you are "splitting" the tree in half every iteration.

**Let's break it down**:

**First Block:**

```
vector<int> v(n);
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
   v[i] = i;
}
```

Here you initialize an `std::vector` of size `n` and use a `for-loop` to initialize the elements. We know that your `for-loop` runs `n-times` and using the `[]` operator does not cost you anything (`O(1)`), hence the time complexity of the **first block** is **`O(n)`**.

[Side Note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376049/vectorat-vs-vectoroperator): use `.at()` instead of the `[]` operator since it gives you "auto" bounds checking.

**Second Block:**

```
set<int> s;
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{
   s.insert(v[i]);
}
```

Here you initialize an `std::set` of integers and you use a `for-loop`, which takes `O(n)` to insert the elements that are in the `std::vector` into your `std::set`. Using `.insert()` takes O(log(N)) time, since in order to find the appropriate spot to insert the element it performs `Binary Search` under the hood. Hence your **second block** takes **`O(Nlog(N))`** time.

Now if you add that together (proof) eg:

```
T(n) = C*f(N) 
     =< N + Nlog(N) (for all n =< 1)
     =< Nlog(N) + Nlog(N) //raise all to the highest power
     =< 2Nlog(N)

since T(n) = C*f(n)
C = 2
f(n) = Nlog(N) //--> your big O
```

The overall time complexity is **`O(Nlog(N))`**. I hope this is enough detail for you.

Comment: The `s.insert(v[i])` does not take O(log n) time. It takes O(log i) time, because the size of the set at that time is i elements (with appropriate treatment for the initial case). The question is not what is the total time for n operations that each take O(log n) time. The question is what is the total time for an operation that takes log 1 time plus an operation that takes log 2 time plus an operation that takes log 3 time, and so on, up to a final operation that takes log n time (with appropriate treatment for O notation)…

Comment: … A proper answer requires a proof that the sum of log i for 1 ≤ i ≤ n is O(n log n). And note this is not true for all functions. For example, the sum of 2^i for 1 ≤ i ≤ n is not O(n•2^n). So you cannot just claim that one would multiply n by log n. A proof is needed.