# C++ array.at(i) and array[i] performances

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, loops

In C++, would it be better (performance-wise) to iterate through elements in an `array` or `vector` using the `array.at(i)` function or by using `array[i]`? Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: `at` performs bounds checking, and `operator[]` does not. So the former does strictly more work than the latter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Vector at/\[\] operator speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578638/c-vector-at-operator-speed)

Comment: Neither one of those member function iterates through the array. They provide indexed access to one element.

Comment: @Pete OP isn’t saying that the functions iterate through the array …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `at()` method performs bounds checking on the passed index, `operator[]` doesn't.

So using `at()` may be slower from a performance perspective if you have lots of element accesses.

(I recall I did some tests with big matrices in an older version of MSVC, and there was a difference between accessing each item with and without bounds checking. As usual, when in doubt, measure.)

Note also that in some implementations like MSVC's one, `operator[]` performs bounds checking in *debug* builds.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: More precisely, it's either the `/MDd` or the `/MTd` compiler flag which enables the checks.

Comment: More accurately, `operator[]` doesn't *have* to perform bounds checking.  So it is implementation dependent whether it does or not.  Typically, optimized builds do not, unoptimized builds often do.

Comment: @Martin Is that true? I’ve never heard of an optimiser that chooses different code paths. *Debug* builds often include checks, true. But how do you even test for the presence of an optimiser in code?

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  In my mind, "an optimized build" is not quite the same as "an optimizer".  An optimized build is likely to run the optimizer, but it will probably also set #define flags to disable time-consuming checks.

Comment: @Martin Alright, but what does this mean in the context of `std::vector::operator[]` then? What are these flags? Or are you talking about debug builds?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I can imagine a bounds check that's labelled `Unreachable` using an implementation `pragma`. The optimizer, seeing that label, would remove the branch, whereas the debug build would simply execute it as written. This would be easier than a whole bunch of `#ifdef`'s.

Answer (score 5):

For [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) or [`std::array::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at),

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, **with bounds checking**.

And for [`std::vector::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) or [`std::array::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at),

> Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos. **No bounds checking is performed**.

So in theory, `operator[]` would be more efficient. In the actual situation, you might measure.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is truly **iterating** through the array, then the iteration code is responsible for ensuring that accesses are not out of bounds. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << my_vec[i] << '\n';
```

There's no need to build in extra overhead by checking whether `i` is out of bounds. It won't be.